# How to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore packages in vs code

Tags: asp.net-core

I tried to install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore` packages using the following commands:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -v 2.1.2
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -v 2.1.2
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design -v 1.1.6
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -v 2.1.5
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools -v 2.0.4
dotnet add package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection -v 5.0.1
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
Build FAILED.

    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Failed to download package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.4' from 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/5.0.4'. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :    Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Failed to download package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.3' from 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore/5.0.3'. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :    Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Failed to download package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.5.0.4' from 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/5.0.4'. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :    Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : The feed 'nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/]' lists package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.4' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.4'. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Failed to download package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.5.0.4' from 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/5.0.4'. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]    
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :    Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. [C:\Users\Pawithra\AspNetAngularAuth\AspNetAngularAuth.csproj]
```

How to install these packages in vs code.

Comment: Are you trying to download the packages in a corporate environment? Is there any proxy configured?

Answer (score 0):

In VS code, open the peoject's .csproj file, add the Nuget Package via the [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files), Code like this (change the .NET Target version and the package's version to yours):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup> 
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.4" /> 
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then, the VS Code may give you a prompt to "restore" pacakges. If not, open the integrated terminal, call `dotnet restore` on command line, and then build the application use `dotnet build`.

Besides, you could also execute the `dotnet add package` commands to install the related packages in VS Code.

Open the [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) in the VS Code, change to the directory (cd) that will contain the project, then run the command: `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -v 2.1.2`.

The result like this:

[image]